# Get asked to confirm safe theme forever

Tags: debugging, themes

I created a theme which I stored in `~/.emacs.d/themes/`, added this
directory to `custom-theme-load-path`, and put `(load-theme
"the-theme.el")` in my `init.el`.  Now restarting emacs, I get
prompted whether really to load, and then whether to consider safe in
future.  I said yes to both and confirmed that the file's SHA256 sum
was put into `init.el`.  But: next time I restart emacs, I get asked
again!  What am I missing?  Running 26.1.

Comment: Are you trying to load the theme *before* your customized variables (with the checksum) have been established in your init file?

Comment: @phils, you're right.  That part of the init was handled by custom, and I didn't consider that my init.el.org was loaded above.

Comment: Great. I've added that as an answer (on the assumption that it did fix the problem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bearing in mind that the init file is an elisp program which is evaluated in sequence, you need to ensure that the call to `load-theme` happens *after* the customized variables have been evaluated; otherwise Emacs doesn't know (yet) that the theme is safe to load.

Answer (score 0):

The described behavior may be also caused by old lisp file. Suppose you have .el and compiled .elc file. You changed the .el file, but not recompiled the .elc, so .el is newer than .elc. Emacs will load the .elc file (without your changes) even when it's older.